# How to sort based on an array inside of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

Let's consider the following JSON response. It is a list of station objects.

```
[
  {
    "id": 43,
    "trucks": [
      {
        "id": 24,
        "vehicleType": {
          "id": 2,
          "vehicleType": "VT",
          "createdAt": 1622645476000,
          "updatedAt": 1622645476000
        },
        "sensor": {
          "id": 16,
          "devId": "tutorial",
          "readings": [
            {
              "id": 36296,
              "interiorTemperature": 528.36,
              "batteryTemperature": 528.36,
              "batteryVoltage": 0,
              "createdAt": 1623065279000,
              "updatedAt": 1623065279000
            }
          ],
          "resolved": false,
          "createdAt": 1622645598000,
          "updatedAt": 1622650553000
        },
        "vehicleNumber": 123456,
        "truckStatus": true,
        "defaultBatteryVoltage": "12",
        "batteryTempThreshold": 25,
        "interiorTempThresholdMax": 30,
        "interiorTempThresholdMin": 5,
        "batteryVoltageThreshold": 11.5,
        "createdAt": 1622645517000,
        "updatedAt": 1622645663000
      },
      {
        "id": 29,
        "vehicleType": {
          "id": 2,
          "vehicleType": "VT",
          "createdAt": 1622645476000,
          "updatedAt": 1622645476000
        },
        "sensor": {
          "id": 23,
          "devId": "value",
          "readings": [
            {
              "id": 36298,
              "interiorTemperature": 10,
              "batteryTemperature": 10,
              "batteryVoltage": 10,
              "createdAt": 1623074142000,
              "updatedAt": 1623074142000
            }
          ],
          "resolved": false,
          "createdAt": 1623074089000,
          "updatedAt": 1623074089000
        },
        "vehicleNumber": 313215,
        "truckStatus": true,
        "defaultBatteryVoltage": "12",
        "batteryTempThreshold": 50,
        "interiorTempThresholdMax": 50,
        "interiorTempThresholdMin": 50,
        "batteryVoltageThreshold": 50,
        "createdAt": 1623073365000,
        "updatedAt": 1623073365000
      }
    ],
    "name": "value",
    "city": "value",
    "address": "value",
    "zipCode": "value",
    "createdAt": 1622645352000,
    "updatedAt": 1622645352000
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "trucks": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "vehicleType": {
          "id": 3,
          "vehicleType": "AG",
          "createdAt": 1622647436000,
          "updatedAt": 1622647436000
        },
        "sensor": {
          "id": 18,
          "devId": "test",
          "readings": [
            null
          ],
          "resolved": false,
          "createdAt": 1622795394000,
          "updatedAt": 1622795394000
        },
        "vehicleNumber": 123457,
        "truckStatus": true,
        "defaultBatteryVoltage": "24",
        "batteryTempThreshold": 80,
        "interiorTempThresholdMax": 50,
        "interiorTempThresholdMin": -20,
        "batteryVoltageThreshold": 11.5,
        "createdAt": 1622645584000,
        "updatedAt": 1623074846000
      }
    ],
    "name": "value",
    "city": "value",
    "address": "value",
    "zipCode": "11112",
    "createdAt": 1622645431000,
    "updatedAt": 1622645431000
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "trucks": [
      {
        "id": 26,
        "vehicleType": {
          "id": 2,
          "vehicleType": "VT",
          "createdAt": 1622645476000,
          "updatedAt": 1622645476000
        },
        "sensor": null,
        "vehicleNumber": 979787,
        "truckStatus": true,
        "defaultBatteryVoltage": "12",
        "batteryTempThreshold": 123,
        "interiorTempThresholdMax": 123,
        "interiorTempThresholdMin": 123,
        "batteryVoltageThreshold": 123,
        "createdAt": 1623064671000,
        "updatedAt": 1623064671000
      }
    ],
    "name": "value",
    "city": "value",
    "address": "value",
    "zipCode": "11111",
    "createdAt": 1622918304000,
    "updatedAt": 1622918304000
  }
]
```

All stations have an id, a list of trucks, and some basic info (name, location etc). With PHP, I convert this to an array object. What I would like to achieve is to sort the array. Now I have managed to sort based on name or location. I used the following snipped:

```
usort($stations, function($a, $b) {
   $retval = $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];
    return $retval;
});
```

Now it's all nice but we would like to sort it based on the highest interior temperature read in a station. To make the station with the highest interior temperature be the 0th element in the list and the one with the lowest (or no reading at all) is the nth. I have tried playing around with usort but I had no results. Is it even possible to sort it like that?

Comment: That's because you trying to sort a float number but Usort its converting that number into a integer one.

Comment: Your "trucks" are in different array levels.
It's not sortable like that. First you have to collect your "trucks" and save them in a table-like structure.